# Bash: Merging 4 lines in 4 files into one single file

Tags: bash, dna-sequence

I'm looking for a way to merge 4 lines of dna probing results into one line.

The problem here is:

I don't want to append the lines. But associating them

The 4 lines of dna probing:

```
A----A----------A----A-A--AAAA-

-CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C

------G----G--G--G------G------

---TT--------T-T---------T-----
```

I need these to be 1 line, not just appended but intermixed without the dashes.

First characters of the result:

```
 ACCTTAGCCCCGC...
```

This seem to be a kind of *general* problem, so the language choosed to solve this don't matter.

Comment: where are the "4 lines" in your input?

Comment: Show the "4 lines" input lines and the desired result. Otherwise it's hard for the community to provide a proper solution.

Comment: @pbaldauf I edited my question,hopefully it gives a better picture of the challenge now.

Comment: I think this could be a fun question for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hm... what is the "logic" getting your wanted output from the above input?

Comment: @jm666 On each column there is only one character a,c,g,t. So in this case the first column gives me A - - -, second one gives me - C - - well then I just need to remove the dashes and do it over and over to make the complete dna sequence.

Comment: You could `cat` all files and pipe to this [tag:perl] filter: `perl -E 'while(<>){y|-|\0|;$r|=$_};say$r'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For fun: one [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way:

```
lines=(
    A----A----------A----A-A--AAAA-
    -CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C
    ------G----G--G--G------G------
    ---TT--------T-T---------T-----
)

result=""
for ((i=0;i<${#lines};i++)) ;do
    chr=- c=()
    for ((l=0;l<${#lines[@]};l++)) ;do
        [ "${lines[l]:i:1}" != "-" ] &&
            chr="${lines[l]:i:1}" &&
            c+=($l)
      done
    [ ${#c[@]} -eq 0 ] && printf 'Char #%d not replaced.\n' $i
    [ ${#c[@]} -gt 1 ] && c="${c[*]}" && chr="*" &&
         printf "Conflict at char #%d (lines: %s).\n" $i "${c// /, }"
    result+=$chr
  done
echo $result
```

With provided input, there is no conflict and all characters is replaced. So the output is:

```
ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

**Note:** Question stand for 4 different files, so `lines=` syntax could be:

```
lines=($(cat file1 file2 file3 file4))
```

But with a wrong input:

```
lines=(
    A----A---A-----A-----A-A--AAAA-
    -CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C
    ------G----G---G-G------G------
    ---TT--------T-T---------T-----
)
```

output could be:

```
Conflict at char #9 (lines: 0, 1).
Char #14 not replaced.
Conflict at char #15 (lines: 0, 2, 3).
Char #16 not replaced.
```

and

```
echo $result
ACCTTAGCC*CGCT-*-GCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

#### Small perl filter

But if input are not to be verified, this little perl filter could do the job:
(Thanks @jm666 for `}{` syntax)

```
perl -nlE 'y+-+\0+;$,|=$_}{say$,' <(cat file1 file2 file3 file4)
```

where

```
-n          process all lines without output
-l          whipe leading cariage return at end of lines
y+lhs+rhs+  replace (translate) chars from 'lhs' to 'rhs'
\0          is the *null* character, binary 0.
$,          is a variable
|=          binary or, between himself and current line ($_)
}{          at END, once all lines processed
```

Comment: Or small perl version with validation: `perl -nlE 'y+-+\0+;$,^=$_}{$_=$,;y*\0*-*;s/[^ACGT-]/*/g;say'`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way - not very efficient - but short:

```
file="./gene"
line1=$(head -1 "$file")
seq ${#line1} | xargs -n1 -I% cut -c% "$file" | paste -s - | tr -cd '[A-Z\n]'
```

prints:

```
ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

Assumption: each line has the same length.

Decomposition:

- the `line1=$(head -1 "$file")` read the 1st line into the variable `line1`
- the `seq ${#line1}` generate a sequence of numbers `1`..`char_count_in_the_line1`, like

```
1
2
..
31
```

- the `xargs -n1 -I% cut -c% "$file"` will run for each above number the command `cut` like `cut -c22 filename` - what extract the given `column` from the file, e.g. you will get output like:

```
A
-
-
-

-
C
-
-

# and so on
```

- the `paste -s -` will join the above lines into one long line with the `\t` (tab) separator, like:

```
A   -   -   -   -   C   -   -   -   C   -   -   -   -   -   T ... etc...
```

- finally the `tr -cd '[A-Z\n]'` remove everything what isn't uppercase character or newline, so will get the final

```
ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

Comment: shorter: `perl -E 'while(<>){y|-|\0|;$r|=$_};say$r' $file`

Comment: you could use `seq $(wc -L <$file)` instead of `head -1...#line1`.

Comment: @F.Hauri the `wc -L` is not portable - e.g. didn't works for example on OS X.

Comment: @F.Hauri - golfing? so, even shorter: `perl -lnE 'y|-|\0|;$r|=$_}{say$r'` :) :) (and didn't prints the exceesive '\n` to the end... ;)

Comment: Thanks @jm666, I'd never used `}{` syntax with `perl -n`!

Comment: with kind of validation: `perl -nlE 'y+-+\0+;$,^=$_}{$_=$,;y*\0*-*;s/[^ACGT-]/*/g;say'` ;-)